# Need help finding closed form of finite product

Tags: arithmetic

Is there a closed form for this product?
$$\prod\limits_{k=1}^n (n+k)$$
I checked it on wolfram alpha but it uses something called the [Pochhammer symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol).  Does anyone else know of a nice explicit closed form or some type of trick to calculate this thing without using the Pochhammer symbol?  Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: $(2n)!/n!{}{}{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\prod_{k=1}^n(n+k)=\prod_{k=n+1}^{2n}k=\frac{\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{2n}k}{\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^nk}=\color{blue}{\frac{(2n)!}{n!}}=n!\cdot\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}=\color{blue}{n!\cdot{2n\choose n}}$$

Comment: +1 thank you! So simple.  I was really tired when I posted this.  It makes perfect sense now :)