# Closed form for finite product $\prod\limits_{j=1}^k\frac{n+j}{n-j}$

Tags: products

I am wondering if the following finite product has a nice closed form.  This appears to be related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709130/need-help-finding-closed-form-of-finite-product) (if the numerator and denominator can be put into closed form seperately), but this one seems more complicated.  Unfortunately this is not really my area, so I don't have much in the way of work to show.  Let $n$ and $k$ be fixed positive integers with $k<n$.

$$\prod_{j=1}^k\frac{n+j}{n-j}$$

Comment: Yet another one: $$\prod_{j=1}^k\frac{n+j}{n-j}=\frac{{2n-1\choose n}}{{2n-1\choose n+k}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product can be written as the ratio of two [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient):
$$\prod_{j=1}^k\dfrac{n+j}{n-j}=\frac{\frac{\prod_{j=1}^k(n+j)}{k!}}{\frac{\prod_{j=1}^k(n-j)}{k!}}=\frac{\binom{n+k}{k}}{\binom{n-1}{k}}.$$
Does it help?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> I'll assume $\ds{n \geq k \geq 1}$:

\begin{align}
\prod_{j = 1}^{k}{n + j \over n - j} & =
\pars{-1}^{k}\,
{\prod_{j = 1}^{k}\pars{j + n} \over \prod_{j = 1}^{k}\pars{j - n}} =
\pars{-1}^{k}\,
{\pars{1 + n}^{\overline{\large k}} \over \pars{1 - n}^{\overline{\large k}}} =
\pars{-1}^{k}\,
{\Gamma\pars{1 + n + k}/\Gamma\pars{1 + n} \over
\Gamma\pars{1 - n + k}/\Gamma\pars{1 - n}}
\\[5mm] & =
\pars{-1}^{k}\,
{\Gamma\pars{1 + n + k} \over \Gamma\pars{1 + n}}
{\Gamma\pars{1 - n} \over \Gamma\pars{1 - n + k}}
\end{align}

> For $\ds{z \not= n}$:

\begin{align}
{\Gamma\pars{1 - z} \over \Gamma\pars{1 - z + k}} & =
{\pi \over \Gamma\pars{z}\sin\pars{\pi z}}\,{\Gamma\pars{z - k}\sin\pars{\pi\bracks{z - k}} \over \pi}
\\[5mm] & =
{\Gamma\pars{z - k} \over \Gamma\pars{z}}
\,\bracks{\cos\pars{\pi k} - \cot\pars{\pi z}\sin\pars{\pi k}} =
{\Gamma\pars{z - k} \over \Gamma\pars{z}}\,\pars{-1}^{k}
\end{align}

> Lets $\ds{z \to n}$:

\begin{align}
\prod_{j = 1}^{k}{n + j \over n - j} & =
\bbx{{\Gamma\pars{1 + n + k} \over \Gamma\pars{1 + n}}\,
{\Gamma\pars{n - k} \over \Gamma\pars{n}}} =
{\pars{n + k}! \over n!}\,
{\pars{n - k - 1}! \over \pars{n - 1}!} =
{\pars{n + k}! \over k!\,n!}\,
{k!\pars{n - k - 1}! \over \pars{n - 1}!}
\\[5mm] & = \bbx{{{n + k \choose k} \over {n - 1 \choose k}}}
\end{align}

Comment: Which package should I add in order \bbx to work?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that
$n > k$;
otherwise there is a
divide by zero.

I am also assuming that
$n$ and $k$ are integers.

$\begin{array}\\
p(n, k)
&=\prod_{j=1}^k\dfrac{n+j}{n-j}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{j=1}^k(n+j)}{\prod_{j=1}^k(n-j)}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{j=n+1}^{n+k}j}{\prod_{j=n-k}^{n-1}j}\\
&=\dfrac{(n+k)!/n!}{(n-1)!/(n-k-1)!}\\
&=\dfrac{(n+k)!(n-k-1)!}{n!(n-1)!}\\
\end{array}
$

For the fun of it,
removing the assumption on $n$
being an integer,

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(p(n, k))
&=\sum_{j=1}^k\ln(\dfrac{n+j}{n-j})\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^k\ln(\dfrac{1+j/n}{1-j/n})\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^k(\ln(1+j/n)-\ln(1-j/n))\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^k(\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m-1}j^m}{n^m}+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{j^m}{n^m})\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^k(\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{j^m}{n^m}((-1)^{m-1}+1)\\
&=2\sum_{j=1}^k\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{j^{2m-1}}{n^{2m-1}}\\
&=2\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^{2m-1}}\sum_{j=1}^kj^{2m-1}\\
&\approx 2\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^{2m-1}}\frac{k^{2m}}{2m}
\qquad\text{(an additional term would make this more accurate)}\\
&=2n\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^{2m}}\frac{k^{2m}}{2m}\\
&=2n\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(k/n)^{2m}}{2m}\\
&=n\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{((k/n)^2)^{m}}{m}\\
&=-n\ln(1-(k/n)^2)\\
\text{so that}\\
p(n, k)
&\approx(1-(k/n)^2)^{-n}\\
\end{array}
$